# HuffmanCode variable bits length per character

Tags: bit, huffman-code

Is there a way to find just the “number of bit” of per character without drawing Huffman tree?
In other words is there a way to find the code length of character via “frequency” or “probability” of character?

Note: I want to use “variable-length code”.
please for explanation use following sentence:

“this is an example of a huffman tree”
For example “a” Huffman code has 3 bit length.

Following site have the Huffman tree, Huffman code and frequency of this sentence: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: If you want the exact number of bits per encoded symbol, then my guess is that the answer is - No, you must use the symbol frequency table (histogram) in order to build a Huffman tree and get the exact bit-encoding for each symbol... but I can't think of any mathematical proof for this conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a rough zero-order entropy of each symbol in a set of symbols.  Given the set of symbols a_i, where the probability of each symbol is p_i (so the sum of the p_i is one), then the entropy of a_i in bits is -log2(p_i), where log2 is a logarithm base two.  The average entropy of a symbol in bits is the sum over i of -p_i log2(p_i).

This gives a rough estimate of what you would get from Huffman or arithmetic zero-order coding of those symbols.  The estimate will provide a lower bound, where both Huffman and arithmetic will not reach the bound due to estimations and, in the case of Huffman, the codes being limited to the resolution of a bit.

Comment: thanks. So there is no way to calculate the exact number of bits

Comment: If want to calculate exactly how many bits a Huffman code will take, then you have to effectively make the Huffman tree.